# ContentNegotiatingViewResolver in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot to develop my web application. I've a requirement to see a search report in 3 formats 1. html 2. pdf and 3. excel. 
Initially i have tested html output and it is working fine. In that, from my controller code i return back the jsp name. `InternalResourceViewResolver` resolves the jsp name for me and jsp is rendered.

Now, to implement the pdf and excel outputs, what approach shall i take? Can i use similar urls shown below

```
http://localhost:8080/SearchCustomers.pdf
http://localhost:8080/SearchCustomers.xls
http://localhost:8080/SearchCustomers
```

If i use above url's then in that case same controller method will be called for each url. The return value from the controller method will be only one value 
ex - return "SearchCustomer"

How to handle above situation and what is the best approach for multiple renders using Spring boot

How does the media types come into picture?

Even if i extend `AbstractPdfView` and `AbstractExcelView` , there bean id's will be different , so they will be ignored as return value from controller method will be different

Comment: Do i know to provide any more info ?